# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13366, 1735

Tags: python, backpropagation

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd


from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split



def import_data():
    pulstars = pd.read_csv("pulsar_stars.csv", index_col=0)
    x = pulstars[["Standard deviation of the integrated profile", "Excess kurtosis of the integrated profile","Skewness of the integrated profile","Mean of the DM-SNR curve","Standard deviation of the DM-SNR curve","Excess kurtosis of the DM-SNR curve","Skewness of the DM-SNR curve"]]
    y = pulstars[["target_class"]]

    return x,y

inp , out = import_data()

out = out.dropna()

#normalize data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
inp = scaler.fit_transform(inp)
out = scaler.fit_transform(out)

classConverter = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
out = classConverter.fit_transform(out)

layer = {
    "input": 8,
    "hidden": 8,
    "output": 2
}

i_h = {
    "weight": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [ layer["input"] , layer["hidden"] ] )),
    "bias": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer["hidden"]]))
}

# weight = {
#     "i_h":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal( [ layer["input"] ], [ layer["hidden"] ] )),
#     "h_o":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([[layer["hidden"]],[layer["output"]]]))
# }

# bias = {
#     "i_h":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer["hidden"]])),
#     "h_o":tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer["output"]]))
# }

h_o = {
    "weight": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer["hidden"],layer["output"]])),
    "bias": tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([layer["output"]]))
}



inp_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, layer["input"]] )
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, layer["output"]])

def feed_forward(inp_dataset):
    x1 = tf.matmul(inp_dataset,i_h["weight"]) + i_h["bias"]
    y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(x1)

    x2 = tf.matmul(y1,h_o["weight"]) + h_o["bias"]
    y2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(x2)

    return y2 #output

output = feed_forward(inp_dataset)

error = tf.reduce_mean(0.5 * (target - output) ** 2)

#back propagation (update weight & bias)
update = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(error)


#split dataset
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp, out, test_size = 0.2)
```

and this happen

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-48df591e9215> in <module>()
     79 
     80 #split dataset
---> 81 x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inp, out, test_size = 0.2)
     82 
     83 

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_consistent_length(*arrays)
    210     if len(uniques) > 1:
    211         raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
--> 212                          " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
    213 
    214 

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [13366, 1735]
```

Answer (score 1):

After you apply `dropna` on your `out`, some rows are removed but the same is not done for your input. Hence, they have different number of rows, leading to your error.